# ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist while connecting through the shell

Tags: sql, oracle, shell

I am trying to run the sql scripts from shell. My scripts are working fine. It is getting connected to database and applying the sql files. Only thing I am not able to understand is why the below error message is getting logged every time.

**Error Message :**

```
ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

**Shell Script:**

```
/opt/ORACLE/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/sqlplus -s <<eoj >>$LOG_FIL 2>&1
${DBUSER1}/${DBPASS}@${hostBillingDBSID}
@${SQLParm} $RPT_FIL 
eoj
```

Comment: The host/server mentioned in the `tnsnames.ora` for `${hostBillingDBSID}` is either unavailable ot not reachable. try to ping the server.

Comment: I am able to ping the host name using tnsping.

Answer (score 1):

try the below.

**Shell Script:**

```
#let's include oracle installation in the PATH variable
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ORACLE/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin

#now just use sqlplus, instead of full path reference.
sqlplus -s ${DBUSER1}/${DBPASS}@${hostBillingDBSID} <<eoj >>$LOG_FIL 2>&1
@${SQLParm} $RPT_FIL 
eoj
```

The `user/password`(connection string) has to be passed as *command line arguments* to `sqlplus`.